# How to reasonable rename package with maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

My project has the following modules:

- client
- rest

The above modules both depend on `com.google.protobuf`, and `rest` depends on `client` (the `rest` module uses `protobuf` jar by `client`).

In order to avoid conflict, I renamed `com.google.protobuf` to `my.com.google.protobuf` in `client` module with `shade` plugin.

The problem is that the `rest` module can not be compiled and reports the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: my.com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor cannot be converted to com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor
```

## Client pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>my-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>client</artifactId>
    <name>Client</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>${protobuf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>client</artifact>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </filter>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>io.my.client.Client</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>my.google</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>shiva.com.google</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## rest pom.xml

```
     <parent>
        <groupId>my-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my-project</groupId>
            <artifactId>clientt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>rest</artifact>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </filter>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>io.my.rest.WebServer</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: please show your code ([mcve])

Comment: you are using `com.google.protobuf` and the shade plugin in a completely wrong way. It sounds strange that a REST module depends on a client.

Comment: @JimHawkins This `rest` provides restful API to access client API

Answer (score 0):

A better workaround seems to be: Right-click on project "client" -> pom.xml in the project view in IntelliJ, choose "Maven" -> "Ignore Projects". Then do a "Maven" -> "Reimport" on the top-level pom.xml.